# Download a zip folder from a remote server and unzip folder from a silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight, out-of-browser

How can i download a zipped folder from a remote server and unzip the entire files in the folder and store them in isolated storage space from a silver light 3 or 4 out of browser application. Any suggestion please

Comment: Can use the Elevated priviledges of Silverlight 4?  Minimum Windows version you wish to support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download a zip file like any files with the Webclient class, look at the details and examples in the msdn documentation for [downloading content on demand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189021(VS.95).aspx) it even talks about how to download and get a specific file from a zip archive.

However if you want to list the files, check out [this blogpost](http://blogs.msdn.com/blemmon/archive/2009/11/25/reading-zip-files-from-silverlight.aspx), I've not actually tried it but it shows how to get all the files in a zip archive.

Edit: I also found [this discussion](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2010/01/11/silverlight-4-displaying-a-bunch-of-files-from-a-zip-file.aspx) which offers some ideas, it among other things mentions this [Small unzip utility](http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2009/04/21/REALLY-small-unzip-utility-for-Silverlight.aspx) for Silverlight, which seems a bit more robust.

Then use the [IsolatedStorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile(VS.95).aspx) class to save the files.

Good Luck!
Ola

Comment: The blog post assumes the entry names are encoded in UTF-8, unfortunately many Zip files will use IBM437 for the character encoding and the zip format doesn't provide a means to determine which encoding was used.

Comment: Good point, the second utility I found, the "Small unzip utility" might be a bit more robust, but then it might have the same flaw, I'm not familiar with zip encoding etc...

Comment: Unfortunately the link to the "Small unzip utititly" is broken as of today...See http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2009/04/22/REALLY-small-unzip-utility-for-Silverlight.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For the (un)zipping I'd highly recommend that you use the open source [DotNetZip library](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). DotNetZip is licensed under the Ms-PL and really easy to use.

Zipping for example is easy too:

```
 using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
 {
     zip.AddEntry("MyFileName.png", null, pngStream);

     // Save to stream from SaveFileDialog
     zip.Save(stream);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Silverlight SharpZipLib](http://slsharpziplib.codeplex.com/) is a full Silverlight 3/4 and Phone7 port, less AES encryption, of [SharpZipLib](http://sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/).

The salient limitation is one that you will find in all Silverlight compression: Only UTF8 encoding of entry meta is supported.

Answer (score -2):

you could get the file using http or frp stream and then use GZipStream (.NET Class) for unziping the stream/file.

GzipStream:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx

Cheers
--Jocke

Comment: System.IO.Compression not present in Silverlight